# initializing members of a list

Tags: python, list, initialization

I want to initialize a list in python. I do not understand why the code below does not work:

```
u = ['abc', 'de', 'fghi', 'jklm', 'n', '']
for item in u:
 item = len(item)
```

There are other ways to initialize the list, like:

```
u = [len(item) for item in u]
```

But, my question is why the first code does not work.

Edit:
I am a newbie to Python, and programming. Unfortunately I do not understand some parts of your answers. For example:
 -  **rebinding** in *"**rebinding** the name `item` to the length of the name `item` "*
 - **iterator** in *"item" is a temporary variable that points to an element of a `u` based on where the **(implicit) iterator** is pointing*
As far as I understand, my second example, creates a `new_list` in memory, and assigns the values of `new_list` to `u`. No matter what the previous values were. But I want to know how I can change the values, in the first list. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, you are not initializing anything. "item" is a temporary variable that points to an element of a u based on where the (implicit) iterator is pointing. If you want to initialize a list in the first style, you can do so as:

```
u = ['abc', 'de', 'fghi', 'jklm', 'n', '']
v = []
for item in u:
     v.append(len(item))
print v
```

Answer (score 3):

You're rebinding the name `item` to the length of the name `item` that was just bound by the loop. You cannot initialize a `list` in this way. All you're doing is rebinding a variable in each iteration. Your list comprehension is a perfectly acceptable method for initializing a `list`.

Comment: item is a string in the first case, since elements of the list u are strings. One can call len() on strings.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the contents of a list just by assigning a new value to a name that represents an entry in that list.  You need to use index assignment, for example to change the first entry in the list to `'foo'` you could do `u[0] = 'foo'`.

In this case you could do something like the following (although the list comprehension from you question is cleaner):

```
for i, item in enumerate(u):
    u[i] = len(item)
```

Note that if the items in your list are mutable you can modify the element directly, you just can't reassign them.  For example with a list of lists:

```
u = [['a'], ['b', 'c']]
for item in u:
    item.append(len(item))
# u is now [['a', 1], ['b', 'c', 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the first code doesn't work is because `item` is just a reference to each iterable object in the sequence `u`. When you say `item = len(item)` you actually do assign `len(item)` to `item`, but since `item` was just acting as a reference pointer pointing to `u[i]` for the i*th* step in your loop, it won't actually change `u[i]` itself.

To change `u[i]` you can do list comprehension like you showed in your question, or do something like:

```
for i in range(len(u)):
    u[i] = len(u[i])
```

A third way is the very useful `enumerate` method introduced in python 2.3.

```
for i, item in enumerate(u):
    u[i] = len(item)
```

`Enumerate` returns a list of tuples created from its argument (don't quote me on this...but it basically *acts* as a list of tuples) where each tuple inside is of the form (index, argument[index]).

Comment: You should have `u[i] = len(item)` in the `enumerate` example.

Answer (score 0):

The first code *does* work. The list `u` is initialized in the first line and the next two lines execute having no effect on the rest of the code - there's no point to them.

```
u = ['abc', 'de', 'fghi', 'jklm', 'n', '']
```

Is initializing the list `u` with contents `['abc', 'de', 'fghi', 'jklm', 'n', '']` - that's all you need to do to initialize a list.

The lines

```
for item in u:
    item = len(item)
```

Just bind the name `item` to all the values in `u` immediately after rebind `item` to the length property of the value one-by-one until the interpreter has worked through the whole list.

Comment: This answer could be improved by telling OP how to actually initialize the list.

Answer (score 0):

`item` is just a **name**. in the `for` loop:

```
for item in u:
```

the `item` is a **reference** to the object to which u[i] **refers**. In other words, `item` and `u[i]` refer to the same object.

but this statement:

```
item = len(item)
```

change the name `item` to **refer** to a int, whose value is len(item).

So nothing changed in the list u.

The list comprehension:

```
u = [len(item) for item in u]
```

is just create a new list, and the **name** u is now a reference to the new list.

If you want to use for loop, you can use the `enumerate` statement:

```
for i, item in enumerate(u):
    u[i] = len(item)
```

That changes the referrings of the items of u **one by one**.